# VBA - Check if recordset has been deleted before updating DB

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm experimenting with VBA and i made the following thingy.

```
Dim rs1 As Recordset
Set rs1 = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("TBL_Registratie")

With rs1
.AddNew
!leerling_Id = Me.leerling_Id
datum = DateValue(!datum_tijd)
tijd = TimeValue(!datum_tijd)
weekDag = Weekday(datum, vbMonday)


Select Case weekDag
    Case 1, 2, 4
        Select Case tijd
            Case "07:00:00" To "08:00:00"
                !score = !score + 1
            Case "16:00" To "16:30"
                !score = !score + 1
            Case "16:31" To "17:00"
                !score = !score + 2
            Case "17:01" To "22:00"
                !score = !score + 3
            Case Else
                Me.txt_resultaat.Caption = "Het is geen opvang"
                Me.txt_resultaat.Visible = True
                ( rs1.close ? ) 
        End Select
```

*other cases*

```
 .Update
 .Close
```

QUESTION: How can i check if my last record in there recordset has a score added or not? if not, i want to delete it and close Else Update & Close

Comment: Not sure i get what you mean, but can you take a record count before any thing happens, at opening, then compare before?

Comment: i edited the question. :)  If i just do .update + .close. He will add a records with the current dayTime but without a score added.. I don't want that. He needs to check if my score has been added before updating and closing.

Comment: rs1.movelast:if isnull(rs1.fields("Score").value)...... or rs1.filter("Name=xyz") etc.

Comment: `rs1.MoveLast:
If (rs1.Fields("score").Value = 0) Then
    rs1.Close
Else
    rs1.Update
    rs1.Close
End If `

He errors on the rs1.Update. - Update without a .addnew

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A much easier way: Calculate the score **before** adding the record, save all needed data in variables instead of recordset fields.

Then only if score > 0 do the `rs1.AddNew` etc.